# Contentful: Linking a list of asset IDs to Entry

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I have a list of asset ids and their json strings like so:

```
ids = ['{"sys": {"type": "Link", "linkType": "Asset", "id": "erwwe"}}', 
       '{"sys": {"type": "Link", "linkType": "Asset", "id": "123"}}', 
       '{"sys": {"type": "Link", "linkType": "Asset", "id": "324234"}}']
```

I'm using python to make entries. How do I file in the files field, which contains links to these assets?

I tried writing this:

```
"files":{
"en-US" : ids
 }
```

But this gives me an error. What is the right way to pass this list to the entry? I'm confused about the linking structure.